After reinstalling Kubuntu which nvidia driver have I to select?
I reinstalled Kubuntu 22.04  and installing
nvidia driver I do not know which driver have I to select ?
I see :
[![Printscreen][1]][1]

https://prnt.sc/acsfbW3MgUFs
Usually I installed 525 (proprietary) - but I do not see in the listing and how to install nvidia driver ?
uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.8.0-49-generic #49~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov  6 17:42:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@master-at-home:/mnt# dpkg -s   nvidia-settings
Package: nvidia-settings
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/x11
Installed-Size: 3012
Maintainer: Ubuntu MOTU Developers <ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
Replaces: nvidia-settings-binary
Provides: nvidia-settings-binary
Depends: pkg-config, screen-resolution-extra (>= 0.18~), libvdpau1, libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0) | libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14.0), libc6 (>= 2.34), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.33.14), libjansson4 (>= 2.3), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libx11-6, libxnvctrl0, libxxf86vm1
Conflicts: nvidia-settings-binary
Conffiles:
 /etc/xdg/autostart/nvidia-settings-autostart.desktop 017c45e084f0cf1051baf9bf5db37d4c
Description: Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
 The nvidia-settings utility is a tool for configuring the NVIDIA
 Linux graphics driver.  It operates by communicating with the NVIDIA
 X driver, querying and updating state as appropriate.  This
 communication is done with the NV-CONTROL X extension.
 .
 Values such as brightness and gamma, XVideo attributes, temperature,
 and OpenGL settings can be queried and configured via nvidia-settings.
Original-Maintainer: Debian NVIDIA Maintainers <pkg-nvidia-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>

Updated Info :
After Running commands :
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

I run with errors :
root@master-at-home:/mnt# ubuntu-drivers install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.21.1ubuntu2) but 1.21.1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
            Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libalgorithm-merge-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

That is fresh installation.
I try to install manually :
root@master-at-home:/mnt# dpkg -s   libdpkg-perl
Package: libdpkg-perl
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: perl
Installed-Size: 2340
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: dpkg
Version: 1.21.1ubuntu2.2
Depends: perl:any, dpkg (>= 1.18.11)
Recommends: libfile-fcntllock-perl, liblocale-gettext-perl, bzip2, xz-utils
Suggests: debian-keyring, gnupg, gpgv, gcc | c-compiler, binutils, patch, sensible-utils, git, bzr
Breaks: dgit (<< 3.13~), pkg-kde-tools (<< 0.15.28~)
Description: Dpkg perl modules
This package provides the perl modules used by the scripts
in dpkg-dev. They cover a wide range of functionality. Among them
there are the following public modules:
.
- Dpkg: core variables
- Dpkg::Arch: architecture handling functions
- Dpkg::Build::Info: build information functions
- Dpkg::BuildFlags: set, modify and query compilation build flags
- Dpkg::BuildOptions: parse and manipulate DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS
- Dpkg::BuildProfiles: parse and manipulate build profiles
- Dpkg::Changelog: parse changelogs
- Dpkg::Changelog::Entry: represents a changelog entry
- Dpkg::Changelog::Parse: generic changelog parser for dpkg-parsechangelog
- Dpkg::Checksums: generate and parse checksums
- Dpkg::Compression: simple database of available compression methods
- Dpkg::Compression::FileHandle: transparently (de)compress files
- Dpkg::Compression::Process: wrapper around compression tools
- Dpkg::Conf: parse dpkg configuration files
- Dpkg::Control: parse and manipulate Debian control information
(.dsc, .changes, Packages/Sources entries, etc.)
- Dpkg::Control::Changelog: represent fields output by dpkg-parsechangelog
- Dpkg::Control::Fields: manage (list of known) control fields
- Dpkg::Control::Hash: parse and manipulate a block of RFC822-like fields
- Dpkg::Control::Info: parse files like debian/control
- Dpkg::Control::Tests: parse files like debian/tests/control
- Dpkg::Control::Tests::Entry: represents a debian/tests/control stanza
- Dpkg::Deps: parse and manipulate dependencies
- Dpkg::Deps::Simple: represents a single dependency statement
- Dpkg::Deps::Multiple: base module to represent multiple dependencies
- Dpkg::Deps::Union: list of unrelated dependencies
- Dpkg::Deps::AND: list of AND dependencies
- Dpkg::Deps::OR: list of OR dependencies
- Dpkg::Deps::KnownFacts: list of installed and virtual packages
- Dpkg::Exit: push, pop and run exit handlers
- Dpkg::Gettext: wrapper around Locale::gettext
- Dpkg::IPC: spawn sub-processes and feed/retrieve data
- Dpkg::Index: collections of Dpkg::Control (Packages/Sources files for
example)
- Dpkg::Interface::Storable: base object serializer
- Dpkg::Path: common path handling functions
- Dpkg::Source::Format: manipulate debian/source/format files
- Dpkg::Source::Package: extract Debian source packages
- Dpkg::Substvars: substitute variables in strings
- Dpkg::Vendor: identify current distribution vendor
- Dpkg::Version: parse and manipulate Debian package versions
.
All the packages listed in Suggests or Recommends are used by some of the
modules.
Homepage: https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg
Original-Maintainer: Dpkg Developers <debian-dpkg@lists.debian.org>

How to fix this issue ?
PS. I have installed PHP 8.2 as I work with it. Could it be the reason that some packages are of lower verions ?
Updated Info #2 :
root@master-at-home:/mnt# sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001341sv00001462sd00001112bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce 840M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

root@master-at-home:/mnt# sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.21.1ubuntu2) but 1.21.1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
            Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libalgorithm-merge-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Updated Info #3:
In my OS I have installed PHP 8.3
master@master-at-home:/mnt$ php -v
PHP 8.3.14 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2024 18:07:16) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.14, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

and check current value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH :
master@master-at-home:/mnt$ echo $PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH

As I have an error :
master@master-at-home:/mnt$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
[sudo] password for master:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.21.1ubuntu2) but 1.21.1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
            Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libalgorithm-merge-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

master@master-at-home:/mnt$ whereis libdpkg-perl
libdpkg-perl:

and
master@master-at-home:/mnt$ apt show      libdpkg-perl
Package: libdpkg-perl
Version: 1.21.1ubuntu2.2
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: perl
Source: dpkg
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Dpkg Developers <debian-dpkg@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 2 396 kB
Depends: perl:any, dpkg (>= 1.18.11)
Recommends: libfile-fcntllock-perl, liblocale-gettext-perl, bzip2, xz-utils
Suggests: debian-keyring, gnupg, gpgv, gcc | c-compiler, binutils, patch, sensible-utils, git, bzr
Breaks: dgit (<< 3.13~), pkg-kde-tools (<< 0.15.28~)
Homepage: https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: Dpkg perl modules
 This package provides the perl modules used by the scripts
 in dpkg-dev. They cover a wide range of functionality. Among them
 there are the following public modules:
 .
  - Dpkg: core variables
  - Dpkg::Arch: architecture handling functions
  - Dpkg::Build::Info: build information functions
  - Dpkg::BuildFlags: set, modify and query compilation build flags
  - Dpkg::BuildOptions: parse and manipulate DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS
  - Dpkg::BuildProfiles: parse and manipulate build profiles
  - Dpkg::Changelog: parse changelogs
  - Dpkg::Changelog::Entry: represents a changelog entry
  - Dpkg::Changelog::Parse: generic changelog parser for dpkg-parsechangelog
  - Dpkg::Checksums: generate and parse checksums
  - Dpkg::Compression: simple database of available compression methods
  - Dpkg::Compression::FileHandle: transparently (de)compress files
  - Dpkg::Compression::Process: wrapper around compression tools
  - Dpkg::Conf: parse dpkg configuration files
  - Dpkg::Control: parse and manipulate Debian control information
    (.dsc, .changes, Packages/Sources entries, etc.)
  - Dpkg::Control::Changelog: represent fields output by dpkg-parsechangelog
  - Dpkg::Control::Fields: manage (list of known) control fields
  - Dpkg::Control::Hash: parse and manipulate a block of RFC822-like fields
  - Dpkg::Control::Info: parse files like debian/control
  - Dpkg::Control::Tests: parse files like debian/tests/control
  - Dpkg::Control::Tests::Entry: represents a debian/tests/control stanza
  - Dpkg::Deps: parse and manipulate dependencies
  - Dpkg::Deps::Simple: represents a single dependency statement
  - Dpkg::Deps::Multiple: base module to represent multiple dependencies
  - Dpkg::Deps::Union: list of unrelated dependencies
  - Dpkg::Deps::AND: list of AND dependencies
  - Dpkg::Deps::OR: list of OR dependencies
  - Dpkg::Deps::KnownFacts: list of installed and virtual packages
  - Dpkg::Exit: push, pop and run exit handlers
  - Dpkg::Gettext: wrapper around Locale::gettext
  - Dpkg::IPC: spawn sub-processes and feed/retrieve data
  - Dpkg::Index: collections of Dpkg::Control (Packages/Sources files for
    example)
  - Dpkg::Interface::Storable: base object serializer
  - Dpkg::Path: common path handling functions
  - Dpkg::Source::Format: manipulate debian/source/format files
  - Dpkg::Source::Package: extract Debian source packages
  - Dpkg::Substvars: substitute variables in strings
  - Dpkg::Vendor: identify current distribution vendor
  - Dpkg::Version: parse and manipulate Debian package versions
 .
 All the packages listed in Suggests or Recommends are used by some of the
 modules.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

What confuse me that in error description I see :
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.21.1ubuntu2) but 1.21.1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed

and apt show   command shows :
Version: 1.21.1ubuntu2.2

Is it the same version that I need ? Why I got this error ?

try in a terminal the command ubuntu-drivers install and the latest driver for your device should be installed.

Sorry, which drivers to select? Please link

ubuntu-drivers devices will list all the drivers, with one "recommended".  ubuntu-drivers install 

Please read Updated Info :

Post these or errors you get: sudo ubuntu-drivers devices &
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

You need the build-essential package to build the nvidia driver, install it.  Not sure how an old version of PHP affects the system, but changing any system parts is not recommended. Isolate any older/newer programs in their own directory, and change your user PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH to pick them up in preference to the system versions.

please read Updated Info #2

please read Updated Info #3

This question is similar to: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
